# Redmine: Change output parameter for Kerio LDAP login

Tags: centos, ldap, redmine

**In Short:**

How can i change Redmine or its settings to modify the data send to LDAP?

I want to remove the MyDomain.de from the following line stated by LDAP:

```
[05/Jan/2016 10:08:12] LDAP: User cn=000000e1,fn=Contacts,fn=public,fn=ContactRoot@MyDomain.de doesn't exist. Attempt from IP address 192.168.1.68.
```

The settings for the Base DN in Redmine are:

```
fn=Contacts,fn=public,fn=ContactRoot
```

**In Long:**

I set up a new Redmine 3.2.0 onto a CentOS 7 machine. Then i imported the uploaded files and sql data of an older Redmine into the new Redmine.

Except for the plugins everything seem to be ported.

I have a Kerio Connect Client running, which handles the login data of the users. The settings in the administration section are the same as in the old Redmine, since they were ported. The problem that now arises is that i can not login with those LDAP users.

I did not set up the old Redmine, but the one who set it up modified something to make it work ... unfortunately he did not write it down...

I had a look in the Logfiles from the old and new Redmine, both are identical in what they logged for the send data to LDAP.

In the LDAP the following error is stated:

```
[05/Jan/2016 10:08:12] LDAP: User cn=000000e1,fn=Contacts,fn=public,fn=ContactRoot@MyDomain.de doesn't exist. Attempt from IP address 192.168.1.68.
```

The problem seems to be the MyDomain.de. The LDAP does not expect this and therefore refuses the login. The settings for the Base DN in Redmine are:

```
fn=Contacts,fn=public,fn=ContactRoot
```

I have none experience with Redmine and LDAP, so has anyone a tip for me how to change this?

**Edit:**
The full Redmine Config:

```
Host: mailserver.MyDomain.de
Port: 389
Account: login@MyDomain.de
Password: ***
Base DN: fn=Contacts,fn=public,fn=ContactRoot
On-the-fly user create = on
```

Attributes:

```
Login attribute: uid
Firstname attribute: givenName
Lastname attribute: sn
Email attribute: mail
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an solution. Open the following file:

> /path/to/redmine/app/models/auth_source_ldap.rb

Then change the followin line:

```
if attrs && attrs[:dn] && authenticate_dn(attrs[:dn], password)
```

to

```
if attrs && attrs[:dn] && authenticate_dn(login, password)
```

This will remove the @myDomain.de . I know that this is not the best solution, but it is a solution.